# Why are there dips in my roof?

Tags: roof, shingles, roofing

I recently walked my roof. There are some low spots, like little depressions. What causes this and should I be concerned? It seems that the plywood underneath is good but it seems like the underlayment has degraded. Is this normal?

Comment: How far apart are your trusses? Do you have any dormers sitting on the roof?

Comment: @aphoria: Not sure what a dormer is

Comment: @0A0D Look at this for an explanation of a dormer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dormer. Sometimes dormers are only architectural elements, meaning they offer no usable space or are even visible from inside. These are called blind dormers. Depending on how your roof was constructed, if a blind dormer is sitting on top of the roof without proper support, it can causing some bowing.

Comment: @aphoria: Definitely no dormers then

Comment: Do you know how far apart the trusses are? How thick the plywood sheeting is?

Comment: @aphoria: I would say the plywood is about 3/4" thick. I may be wrong. Trusses are about 1-2 feet apart I estimate.

Comment: Have you checked in your attic or crawl space?  Anything suspicious up there?  Any recent construction/demolition in the attic or crawl space?

Comment: @Jeff: Nothing suspicious that I can see

Comment: Is it a flat or pitched roof?

Comment: @ChrisF: I'm guessing flat and at about 45 degree angle.

Comment: How big are the "little depressions"?

Comment: @Tester101: 1 foot across maybe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Plywood generally doesn't sag permanently unless it's been wet for an extended period of time. Can you get into the attic to check for water stains around those areas?